# GCP Object download metric

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is there a metric that can be used to determine how many times an object has been downloaded from a GCP bucket?

Comment: Are these objects public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logs) to track storage activity from authenticated users.

For getting how many times an object has been viewed, you have [to enable](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-enable) the **DATA_READ** access logs.

Then, you can search on the [Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/) using this [advanced filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters):

```
resource.type="gcs_bucket"
resource.labels.bucket_name=[BUCKET_NAME]
logName="projects/[project_id]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"
protoPayload.resourceName="projects/_/buckets/[bucket_name]/objects/[object_name]"
```

Note that this only works if the object has **not public** access.

Answer (score 1):

It may be Metrics on Stackdriver Monitoring.

- api/request_count
- authz/acl_based_object_access_count
- network/sent_bytes_count
- etc

See https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp?hl=ja#gcp-storage .